# After removing foreach, no data is displayed

Tags: php

Enrol table:
[image]

From this table I try get value from `active_shop`

Here I have code:

```
<?php 
$get_config_details = $this->db->get('enrol',$per_page, $this->uri->segment(1));
?>
<?php if ($get_config_details->num_rows() > 0):
                foreach($get_config_details->result_array() as $get_config_detail):
                    $course_details = $this->crud_model->get_course_by_id($get_config_detail['course_id'])->row_array();?>
<?php echo $get_config_detail['active_shop']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Now I get the result: `1`

But I copied this function from another function. I don't need the `foreach` function and `if` and so much code here. I need some simple code to squeeze this table and `echo` the result. Can anyone help me to correct this code?

Comment: What framework are you using? If `$this->db` is mysqli perhaps `fetch_all` could be used then implode the data and output?

Comment: Exactly, what's the part you need?